Bilingual two-page parallel typesetting with bilingual headers drawn from section and chapter names
The book I'm trying to typeset is a bilingual parallel liturgical text (a lectionary). As such, I'll need the chapters and sections to be in both languages, on facing pages. Only the chapters and sections need to be synchronised in their vertical positions --- the body paragraphs in each section are very short, so it's preferred to have a bit of trailing space at the end of a section in one language instead of gaps in between paragraphs when one language "waits" for the other language's next paragraph.
A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a "mock up" of the effect I'm trying to achieve (done by manually typing things out in the article class):

For the custom headers I've attempted fancyhdr, and with the parallel facing pages I've attempted to use reledmac with reledpar, and also the parallel package, but it seems it's impossible to have LaTeX track two simultaneous 'trees' of chapters and sections, and then have them referenced in the header (and later used in a second TOC). (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)
To this end I've attempted to manually set the LO, RO, LE, and RE headers with \fancyhead whenever a new section/chapter is called (see MWE below for code). To my dismay they seem to not work within the parallel \begin{pages} \end{pages} environment of reledpar, nor the Parallel environment of parallel.
Here's the minimal non-working code:
MWE with reledmac+reledpar
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[punct=quanjiao]{ctex} % automatically switch to CJK font when needed, based on LuaTeX-ja

\usepackage[includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=4.5in,paperheight=7in,vmargin=1cm,hmargin=1.2cm} % Post Octavo paper size

\usepackage{titlesec}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy} % Chapters by default use the plain pagestyle on their first page. This overrides that.
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\LARGE\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-60pt}{0pt} % Remove the vertical spacing around new chapters
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\Large\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % We don't want a horizontal rule in the header
\fancyfoot{} % clear the default one first before setting out own
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\small\thepage} % right and left page numbers for odd and even pages respectively

\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac} % Loads of stuff for scholarly typesetting, the options disable unneeded stuff to make it run faster, see "4.2 Optimizing package performance" for details
\usepackage{reledpar} % Parallel typesetting, add-on to reledmac
\numberlinefalse % reledmac option, since we don't need line numbers

%%%%% Lectionary commands %%%%%
\newcommand{\echap}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1} \eledchapter*{#1} \doinsidethislinehook{\fancyhead[LE]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cchap}[1]{\addcontentsline{ctoc}{chapter}{#1} \eledchapter*{#1} \doinsidethislinehook{\fancyhead[RO]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\esec}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1} \eledsection*{#1} \doinsidethislinehook{\fancyhead[RE]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\csec}[1]{\addcontentsline{ctoc}{section}{#1} \eledsection*{#1} \doinsidethislinehook{\fancyhead[LO]{#1}}}
%%%%% End of Lectionary commands %%%%%

\begin{document}
Title page
\clearpage
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar

    \echap{Year A}

    \esec{First Sunday of Advent}

    A reading from the book of the prophet Isaiah.

    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar

    \cchap{甲年}

    \csec{將臨期第一主日}
    
    恭讀以賽亞先知書。

    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}

The results are this, note the missing headers:

The attempt with the parallel package is even worse as it doesn't support parallel sections and chapters. If I do a manual \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1} \chapter*{#1} \fancyhead[LE]{#1} within the \begin{Parallel} \end{Parallel} environment, the \fancyhead is likewise not picked up.
I've also tried calling these \fancyhead commands outside the Parallel and pages environments:
\fancyhead[RE]{Section name}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering \autopar
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section name} \eledsection*{Section name}
    % etc.
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

By doing this the \fancyhead commands are picked up, but then every time I close these environments reledpar would clear a double page --- which I don't want, since the next section needs to continue on the same double page spread. And I can't call a new section within the same pages environment because \fancyhead doesn't work within it.
Does anyone know if this is doable? I'm out of ideas and pulling my hair.

I know it is doable using paracol (see section 7.4 of the paracol manual)  Reledmac maybe.

@JohnKormylo I tried paracol, but:

fancyhead doesn't work within the paracol environment
The page numbers go wonky. With the parallel pages config, you get page 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, etc.


Actually, I meant section 9.  Anyway, \begin{paracol}[1]*{2} will give each page a new number.
